# Redirect does not output anything into the files

Tags: command-line, batch, shell-script, cmd.exe

I have the following batch script which executes several processes and is supposed to redirect their outputs into some log files, howeever when the processes finish running the files are empty even though I can see the windows being filled with texts.

```
@echo off
set /p guid=Please enter GUID:
start /wait Debug\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test map %guid% > map.txt
start /wait Debug\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test compare %guid% > compare.txt
start /wait Debug\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test analyse %guid% > analyse.txt
start /wait Debug\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test update %guid% > update.txt
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### When the processes finish running the files are empty

Your redirect `>` is redirecting the output of `start`, instead of the output of `Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe`.

In addition the syntax of your `start` command is incorrect. The first parameter shoud be a "Title" (which is required, not optional).

You can remove the `start /wait`, it is not needed.

```
@echo off
set /p guid=Please enter GUID:
Debug\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test map %guid% > map.txt
Debug\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test compare %guid% > compare.txt
Debug\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test analyse %guid% > analyse.txt
Debug\Debug\Ylp.Web.CmsImportWebJob.exe /test update %guid% > update.txt
pause
```

---

#### Start - Start a program, command or batch script

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
> ```
>
> **Key**:
>
> ```
> title       Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
> path        Starting directory.
> command     The command, batch file or executable program to run.
> parameters  The parameters passed to the command.
> ```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).